# A question about precedence and associativity in C

Tags: c, compilation, operator-keyword, operator-precedence

I had a question about something I'm failing to understand.

Since white space removal is part of `C` compiling process, then how does a C compiler differentiates between the following:

Case1:

```
int x = 2,y=4;
int z = x+++y;
printf("%d", z);//gives 6
```

Case 2:

```
 int x = 2,y=4;
 int z = x+ ++y;
 printf("%d", z);//gives 7
```

Notice the space I added after `x+`, making the `++` stick to the `y` rather than the `x`, but how does this happen if white spaces are removed?

Comment: But then your question is some kind of misleading as if you have a confusion about precedence & associativity, rather than how the white spaces are differentiated in expression evaluation

Answer (score 3, accepted):

C has a greedy left-to-right lexer:

[http://port70.net/~nsz/c/c11/n1570.html#6.4p4](http://port70.net/%7Ensz/c/c11/n1570.html#6.4p4):

> If the input stream has been parsed into preprocessing tokens up to a
> given character, the next preprocessing token is the longest sequence
> of characters that could constitute a preprocessing token.

...

so `+++` must be recognized as `++` `+` and never as `+` `++`.

Precedences and associativities then determine how the `++` or the `+` token bind ([http://port70.net/~nsz/c/c11/n1570.html#A.2.1](http://port70.net/%7Ensz/c/c11/n1570.html#A.2.1)).

Simply put, postfix  operators bind tighter than prefix operators, which bind tighter than binary operators. So `x++ + y` means `(x++) + (y)` and never `(x) (++(+(x))` (which would be nonsensical for other reasons) (and e.g., `&x->member` means `&(x->member)` and not `(&x)->member`), but the confusion here only seems to be in how the fragment is tokenized.

Comment: This example in the page you provided "The program fragment x+++++y is parsed as x ++ ++ + y, which violates a constraint on increment operators" is pretty clear to make this point understandable, thanks very much!

Answer (score 2):

Well, white spaces are not completely ignored by the lexical analyzer which job it is to get the tokens and pass them to the parser.

In the first case, the tokens `x`, `++`, `+`, `y` where found by the lexer, while in the second case, `x`, `+`, `++`, `y` were found by the lexer.

So it's less a matter of operator priority (which stay the same) than the way the lexical analyzer interprets the source code.

@PSkocik provides a very good reference.

To clarify for non Computer Science graduates, a token is a sequence of characters that represent a language entity such as a variable, an operator, a keyword (if, while, for, int, float...)

Comment: I had a question, so does the lexical analyzer step/tokenising take place before the white space removal step?

Comment: The lexical analyzer is the one that decides how to interpret white spaces and figure out if and how they should be used to separate tokens. So it's not just a simple rule that says remove white spaces.

Comment: It's not before or after. The lexical analyser is told to skip any whitespace as a separate rule. It is most likely implemented as a rule that does nothing and creates no output token for it.